# Google Ad mob SDK for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xamarin, windows-runtime, xamarin.forms, windows-phone-8.1, admob

Does Google Ad mob SDK currently supports Silverlight (WP8/WP8.1 Silverlight) only? How can implement it on Windows phone 8.1 RT platform?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.  According to https://developers.google.com/admob/ the official SDK is for Android, iOS, Unity and Cocos2dx.

You way want to have a look at Smaato (https://www.smaato.com/resources/sdks/) which seems to be a 3rd party framework that supports Admob and had Windows Phone 8.1 SDK's, not a recommendation so please do your own research

Answer (score 0):

AdMob  is no longer supported by Windows Phone applications.
google stopped their support to windows phone